# Segmentation fault (core dump) - for loop with multidimensional vector C++98

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, c++98

I am getting a segmentation fault (core dumped) error when I try to run this program on Ubuntu 14.04 terminal. It got compiled correctly but when I run the program it gives me a segmentation fault (core dumped). I know the problem is with the nested for loop block right there because when I remove that part,

```
for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < 500; j++){
     map[i][j] = "unknown";
   } 
 }
```

the program works just fine, but if I include the block of code above it doesn't. Below is the whole program in progress:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int moves = 0;
string input;
vector< vector<string> > map;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

 for(int i = 0; i< 500; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j< 500; j++){
   map[i][j] = "unknown";
   } 
 }

  while ( 1 ) {
    getline(cin, input); 
    cout << "#"<< input[0] << endl; 
    cout << "#"<< input[2] << endl;
    cout << "#"<< input[4] << endl;
    cout << "#"<< input[6] << endl;
    cout << "#"<< input[8] << endl;

    cout << "forward" << endl;

  }

  for(int i = 0; i< map.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < map.size(); j++){
      cout << "#" << map[i][i] << endl;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Any expert out there who can help identify the problem?

Comment: In addition to the answer, also understand that "map" is already defined in the std namespace. It's one of the standard containers. What you've done is similar to list<list<string>>vector;

Comment: Thank you tipaye that helps a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your snippet

```
for(int i = 0; i < 500; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j < 500; j++){
     map[i][j] = "unknown";
   } 
 }
```

tries to access elements of the vector that do not exist.  Accessing elements outside the vector will *not* create them automatically (unlike map).

Either use `vector::push_back` to insert elements or call `vector::resize` before your loops.